# Why do I have to Delete the DerivedData project folder every time I Run on an iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I have an iPad application that reads a whole bunch of pList and .csv files.

For some reason, when I build and run the app (Using the Simulator or an iPad) changes made to the csv and plist files are not reflected in the application unless I delete the project's derived data folder.

Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Are the csv and plist in a separate folder inside your project? I'm not sure if this ever changed, but it used to be that Xcode didn't check the modified date of files inside folders when copying the resources, but only the folder's modified date.